# Multiple domains under one IP but direct IP entry shows apache page

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, ip

I'm hosting around 15 domains under a single IP and everything works fine but when I visit the IP (http://IPaddyHERE) it shows me the apache page.

How can I either redirect it to one of my domains or show a blank page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a default virtual host defined in your `httpd.conf` that will handle web requests on the IP address itself. It will appear first in the list of VirtualHost's and the `ServerName` tag is typically set to the server IP address rather than a domain name.

**Example:**

```
<VirtualHost 104.37.179.4:80>
    ServerName 104.37.179.4
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
    ServerAdmin admin@yourwebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want to show a blank page, simply modify the index.htm or index.html contained in the `DocumentRoot` directory. In my example above, that directory would be `/usr/local/apache/htdocs`.

If you want it to display your website, then you could change the `DocumentRoot` to reflect the web directory of your website.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Elliot. I can't find any httpd.conf file anywhere :/

Comment: Found the index.html file under `/var/www/html` after all